# passport.js deserializeUser not modifying req.user

Tags: express, passport.js

I am not seeing any effect on the `req.user` or `req.session.passport.user` objects as a result of `deserializeUser()`.

My understanding is that successful completion of `deserializeUser()` should result in my User object which *I* retrieve from a DB should be set to the `req.user` property.  *Is this correct?*

Furthermore, it seems that the purpose of this callback is to allow me to serialize a small object (e.g.:  `{username: 'me', email: 'me@me.com'}`) in the cookie itself, but then add more user info retrieved from the database to use downstream.

Instead, I see the following:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    // user: 'stan@stadelman.com'
    fetchUser(user, function(u) {
        // u: { email: 'stan@stadelman.com', name: 'Stan Stadelman' }
        done(null, u);
    });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    // id: { email: 'stan@stadelman.com', name: 'Stan Stadelman' }
    fetchUser(id.email, function(user) {
        // user: { email: 'stan@stadelman.com', name: 'Stan Stadelman',    local_props: 'from_db'}
        done(null, user);
    });
});

req.user = 'stan@stadelman.com'
req.session = { cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: { user: { email: 'stan@stadelman.com', name: 'Stan Stadelman'    } } }
```

My expectation was that the `req.session.passport.user` and/or `req.user` objects should contain the `local_props` property value.  Am I reading the documentation & tutorials incorrectly, or is there an issue?  I've cross-posted in passport.js github [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/409).

*My express & passport setup is as follows:*

```
// express configs
app.use(cookieParser(expressSecret));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressSession({ 
    secret: expressSecret, 
    resave: true, 
    saveUninitialized: true }
));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport implementation
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(/...));
```

Comment: I found a workaround by writing to `req.res.locals` array, which isn't exactly how I think it's supposed to work: [workaround](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/409#issuecomment-140215559)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass user id to done callback in serialize

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});
```

And then use that id to fetch user in deserialize

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) { 
    fetchUser(id, function(user) {
        done(null, user); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, but I'm not sure this is functionally different than what is currently being done... I am actually not having any issue passing either a single string (a `user.id`) or JSON object from `serializeUser()` to `deserializeUser()`.   You can see this where the `id` parameter in `deserializeUser()` is equal to the `user` value I sent to `done()` in `serializeUser()`.  The issue I'm seeing is in the next step:  the callback `done()` in `deserializeUser()` is not passing the JSON object to the `req`.

Comment: Debug and make sure  that `fetchUser` is returning a proper user. You can log as string to console by using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: What constitutes a proper 'User'?  Do I own the definition, or is there a pre-defined model?  The current return is as follows:  `// user: { email: 'stan@stadelman.com', name: 'Stan Stadelman', local_props: 'from_db'}`

Comment: @Stan, a proper user means a non-null value or object and the user object you've given is perfect. And no, there is no pre-defined model and you control it completely. Saving only id in `serializeUser` is to reduce the size of data saved in session. Instead of `passport.use(new BasicStrategy(/...));` try using `passport.authenticate(passport.use('UserBasic', new UserBasicStrategy(
    function (email, password, callback) {
  ...
    }
)), {session: true});`

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar problem but caused by something else. Passport.js `deserializeUser()` does its job setting user object to `req.user`:

```
passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
  try {
    const account = await Account.findById(id);
    done(null, account);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error, null)
  }
});
```

However, in order to check whether a user is logged in, I have a route on the server /account/me that takes `req.user` and returns it as json:

```
router.route('/account/me').get(mwAuthentication, (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.user);
});
```

To filter sensitive properties, I have a method toJSON() defined in Mongoose schema:

```
AccountSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  let account = this;
  let accountObject = account.toObject();
  return _.pick(accountObject, ['_id', 'fullName', 'email', 'facebookId', 'photoUrl']);
};
```

When you call `res.json(req.user)` it calls `JSON.stringify(req.user)` internally, which again calls my `toJSON()` method and limits the object to properties that I picked.

Hope this helps someone.